# Build a zoomable sunburst within a shiny app

Tags: d3.js, shiny, sunburst-diagram, r2d3

I'm building a dataViz application using shiny, I'm wondergin if there is a possiblity to embeed a zoomable sunburst diagram using package r2d3 or whatever ?

I've been trying to implement the code here https://bl.ocks.org/vasturiano/12da9071095fbd4df434e60d52d2d58d
but it doesn't work,

Has anyone already done something like that ?

Kinds.

Comment: google leads me here: https://github.com/timelyportfolio/sunburstR.

Comment: sunburstR package doesn't allow to make zoomable sunburst chart.

Comment: actually in the examples section you can find one which is almost like the link you posted. https://github.com/timelyportfolio/sunburstR/tree/master/inst/examples